# Umbraco setting image error

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

in my umbraco setting, i dont have any image logo to upload my image that was saved in my Media folder, only insert umbraco page field and insert umbraco macro  logo was there.I tried many links but it was unsuccessful.im using umbraco V3.0.5

Comment: Version 3? Then why the umbraco5 tag?

Comment: @marapet It would be a shocker to go back to v3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're modifying a template (you have access to insert field and insert macro) and you want to add an image that is saved in your media section.

Are you really using Umbraco 3 - that is a few years old now and the syntax is very different and you will probably need to use xslt; for example inserting a macro will look different on your template for v3 and v4 (v5 has been deprecated and v6 is not live yet).

(http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/templates/umbracomacro-element/macro-parameters/advanced-macro-parameter-syntax)

Umbraco Version 3:

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="RenderProperties" pageValue="[#bodyText]" />
```

Umbraco Version 4:

```
<umbraco:macro alias="RenderProperties" pagevalue="[#bodyText]" runat="server"/>
```

In the older versions of umbraco putting an image onto a page from media required writing some xslt and referring to it in a macro - this example (that I've dredged up) would display the image that was picked for a page with an alias of 'imageAliasName'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:umbraco.contour="urn:umbraco.contour" xmlns:PS.XSLTsearch="urn:PS.XSLTsearch"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets umbraco.contour PS.XSLTsearch ">


<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="mediaId" select="number($currentPage/imageAliasName)" />
    <xsl:if test="$mediaId > 0">
      <xsl:variable name="mediaNode" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($mediaId, 0)" />
      <xsl:if test="$mediaNode/umbracoFile">

        <img>
          <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:text>/ImageGen.ashx?image=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$mediaNode/umbracoFile"/>
            <xsl:text>&amp;width=200</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&amp;height=200</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

in V3 i insert that image in to one of my content file from there i can view the id for my image..using that id image to write my code in my setting..when i write my image logo was viewed successful.